# How to apply a hazard ratio to a flexsurv model in R?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have a flexsurv model and I am wondering if it is possible to plot a curve that has a hazard ratio x (where x >=0)? E.g. I would like to test how curves would look like when I set hazard ratios to different levels. I would want to do this with all the general distributions and spline models.

For example, how can I plot a curve that has a HR=2 compared to the curve below?

```
library(flexsurv)
library(survival)

data <- survival::lung
formula <- Surv(time, status) ~1
fsmodel<-flexsurvreg(formula,dist = "weibull", data = data)

plot(NULL,type='n', main = "", xlim = c(0,450), ylim = c(0,1),ylab = "Survival probability (%)",xlab = "Time (months)")
lines(fsmodel)
```

Thanks,
gibsonmate

**EDIT**

I tried to show what I am trying to achieve, I am just not sure if it is correct statistically or if there is a better way?:

```
summary<- data.frame(summary(fsmodel, t=1:450, type = "survival"))

HR <- 2.0

summary$est_HR <- summary$est^HR
lines(x=summary$time, y=summary$est_HR)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to show. You mention hazard *ratios*. You need (at least) two conditions under which to compare data (and hazards). In other words, the hazard ratio compares data under a certain condition with reference data. But in your model `Surv(time, status) ~ 1` you don't account for different conditions. Are you perhaps confusing hazard ratio with hazard function?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am just trying to show a hypothetical scenario that shows how  the curves would look like given different levels of relative effectiveness. I tried to show what I am trying to achieve, I have added some code to my question. Could you please check?

Comment: Any update on this issue?